# Generic access to variable keyed object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

let's assume I have the following interfaces (extremely simplified from my project):

```
interface A {};
interface B {};

interface State {
  a: A[];
  b: B[];
}
```

and the following function:

```
function getData<T extends keyof State>(name: T): State[T] {
  return state[name];
}

getData('a') // returns strongly typed A[]
getData('b') // returns strongly typed B[]
```

This turns out to be super useful for multiple apps of mine and I would like to put in a library. Sadly it depends directly on `State`, so I need a new interface that is generic enough to describe any kind of state where the keys (a,b) are generic (so no fixed name, no fixed type) to replace the `State` in the functions signature - while still returning a strong type from `getData`, so something like this (I know this doesnt work, it's just pseudo code):

```
interface StateDescribing {
  [key: string]: SomeGenericMagic
}

function getData<U extends StateDescribing, T extends keyof u>(state: U, name: T): U[T] {
  return state[name];
}
```

Any ideas on how to write that interface?

Comment: What is the role of `StateDescribing` do you want to restrict the structure of state fields in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need any restrictions on `U` if you just want to return a value from `U`. This will work fine:

```
interface A { };
interface B { };

interface State {
    a: A[];
    b: B[];
}

declare var state: State;

function getData<U, T extends keyof U>(state: U, name: T): U[T] {
    return state[name];
}

getData(state, 'a') // returns strongly typed A[]
getData(state, 'b') // returns strongly typed B[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any interface:

```
function getData<T, K extends keyof T>(state: T, name: K): T[K] {
  return state[name];
}


const a = getData('hola', 'length'); // a: number. OK
const b = getData(23, 'toString'); // b: function. OK
const c = getData(23, 'length'); // error. No 'length' in number
```

And this function works for every object, not only for particular types